# Trying to convert file size to readable in a Visual Studio project - how to combine with my existing code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, filesize, human-readable

I am working with a Visual Studio model, and I have a page for "downloads" that displays file name, file size, and a link.  However, I am trying to convert the file size to a readable format.  I have found several methods for doing this, but I think where I am getting stuck is how to incorporate that into the code that I am already using.  For instance, I already have a FileSize variable, so I want to incorporate that into the code for the conversion.  Here is my existing code for the model itself:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.Hosting;

namespace SupportToolkit.Models
{
public class DataClassesModel
{
    public List<FileNames> GetFiles()
    {

        List<FileNames> lstFiles = new List<FileNames>();
        DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Files"));

        int i = 0;
        foreach (var item in dirInfo.GetFiles())
        {

            lstFiles.Add(new FileNames()
            {
                FileId = i + 1,
                FileName = item.Name,
                FileSize = item.Length,
                FilePath = dirInfo.FullName + @"\" + item.Name,
                FileExtension = item.Extension
            });
            i = i + 1;
        }

        return lstFiles;
    }
}



public class FileNames
{
    public int FileId { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public long FileSize { get; set; }
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
    public string FileExtension { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I want to add some code in here to do the conversion to KB, MB, GB, etc. - and I have an idea, but don't know how to incorporate it into what I already have.  Here is an example of what I am going for with conversion:

```
public static string FileSizeFormat(this long FileSize)
    {
        double size = FileSize;
        int index = 0;
        for (; size > 1024; index++)
            size /= 1024;
        return size.ToString("0.00 " + new[] { "B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB" }[index]);
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  I am very new to this and am just stuck on how to blend these two things together.  :)

Thank you.

Let me also add the code used in Index.html, maybe that will help complete the circle.  I am trying to figure out how to get the formatted file size to show on this page.  Thank you.

```
@using SupportToolkit.Models
@model IEnumerable<SupportToolkit.Models.FileNames>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Downloads</h2>

<hr />

<table>
<tr>
    <th>
        File Name
    </th>

    <th>
        File Size
    </th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr >
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FileName)
        </td>

        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FileSize)
        </td>

        <td>
            <p style="text-indent: 5em;">
                @Html.ActionLink("Download", "Download", new { id = item.FileId })
            </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

In this instance, I am using @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FileSize) to display the file size.  But that does not include the formatting.  How would I make this the formatted file size (human-readable)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get a human-readable file size in bytes abbreviation using .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/281640/how-do-i-get-a-human-readable-file-size-in-bytes-abbreviation-using-net)

Comment: I understand how to get the human-readable file size.  What I do not understand is how to incorporate that into the code I am already using.  I was very clear about explaining that.  In fact, the link you posted I believe is where I got the code to use for how to convert the file size.  That is not the issue.  The issue is that I am looking for some guidance on how to combine this method with the code I have already written.  I posted both my existing code and the method I want to use for conversion.  The question is how do I use them together?

Comment: Specifically - how do I take the "FileSize = item.length" I am already using and convert that to human-readable?  How would my current code incorporate the conversion?

Comment: @LilithGoddess: it's not exactly clear what you're asking. Obviously, invoking `FileSizeFormat` with the `FileSize` (i.e. `item.Length`) parameter will return the `string` representation you are asking for. But it's impossible to tell what you actually want to do with this string. Dump it to a console? Save it to a text file? Or do you want to add a new `string` property inside `FileNames` and so that `GetFiles` assigns the string value to this property? Usually, you do the formatting at the end (before printing/rendering). Btw. better name for the class should be `FileName`, singular.

Comment: Also, you don't need to concatenate `dirInfo.FullName + @"\" + item.Name`, just use `item.FullName` instead, it already contains the full path.

Comment: I can further explain, thanks for the question!  with that string, I would be using it in an "index.html" and calling it to be displayed in a table.  i.e.  "@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FileSizeFormat)".

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you defined `FileSizeFormat` as an extension method of `long`.

In that case, you can call, e.g., `lstFiles[0].FileSize.FileSizeFormat()` and it will return the readable string.

Don't forget to add `using XXX` where `XXX` is the namespace where you defined `FileSizeFormat` method.

Consider renaming `FileSizeFormat` to `ToReadableFileSize()`. It will make your code more 'readable' - `lstFiles[0].FileSize.ToReadableFileSize()`.

Comment: Thank you - so, my question is.  Currently, in index.html, the way I am displaying the file size in a table is by using "@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FileSize)".  This works fine, except does not contain the formatting.  So I thought I could use "@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FileSize.FileSizeFormat)" to include the formatting, but that does not compile.  Am I doing this incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, after much time.  Figured I would post just so others could learn from it that may have the same learning curve.  ;)

I changed just one line of code.  In the model itself:

```
FileSize = item.Length,
```

Now reads:

```
FileSize = FileSizeFormat(item.Length),
```

I also removed the static, from the public string, as it was not needed.

Nothing else had to change.  That's it.  Thanks!