# How to convert file size in datagridview column value C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I`m making windows application.

In my application working process is like this

1. Write text in Text Box and click Start button
2. Matched data showed in DataGridView

And now I want to convert to file size in Datagridview column

For example, In my database, DBsize value saved in byte foramt like this : 451936256

but It`s hard to count it, So in DataGridView, I want to show convert it like this : 431MB

I showed my button click code below, How can I do that? Please help me.

Thank you

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string webApplicationName = string.Empty;
            string siteID = string.Empty;
            mtlblError.Text = "no record returned";

            Migration_Status_DAC dac = new Migration_Status_DAC();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            try
            {

                ds = dac.SelectWebApplicationStatus(mtextUrl.Text);
                DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];


                if (ds != null && dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {

                    mgrdWebApplication.DataSource = dt;
                }
                else
                {
                     mtlblError.Visible = true;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                LogWrite.writeLog(ex.ToString();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Add one of methods from [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/281640/how-do-i-get-a-human-readable-file-size-in-bytes-abbreviation-using-net) to convert bytes to human readable format. Then handle `CellFormatting` event of `DataGridView` and set `e.Value` using that method.

Comment: Thanks you Reza Aghaei. I understand what you say but this is my first
time to use it.. Please can you explain it more detail??

Comment: *[`DataGridView.CellFormatting`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting(v=vs.110).aspx) event lets you indicate the exact display value as well as the cell styles, such as background and foreground color, to use for the cell display. This means you can handle this event for any kind of cell formatting, regardless of whether the cell value itself needs formatting.*

Comment: Thank you. 
Finally I did it. I really appreciate with you.

Comment: Don't forget to vote for linked question and the answer which you used to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I completed my code, advice from Reza Aghaei.

At first using CellFormatting event

```
private void mgrdContentDatabase_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if(this.mgrdContentDatabase.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderText== "Size(GB)")
    {
        if (e.Value != null)
        {
            CovertFileSize(e);
        }
    }
}
```

And Next Convert file size Method.

```
private void CovertFileSize(DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs formatting)
        {
            if (formatting.Value != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    long bytes;
                    bytes = Convert.ToInt64(formatting.Value);
                    string size = "0 Bytes";

                    //GB
                    if (bytes >= 1073741824.0)
                        size = String.Format("{0:##.##}", bytes / 1073741824.0) + " GB";
                    //MB
                    else if (bytes >= 1048576.0)
                        size = String.Format("{0:##.##}", bytes / 1048576.0) + " MB";
                    //KB
                    else if (bytes >= 1024.0)
                        size = String.Format("{0:##.##}", bytes / 1024.0) + " KB";
                    //Bytes
                    else if (bytes > 0 && bytes < 1024.0)
                        size = bytes.ToString() + " Bytes";

                    formatting.Value = size;
                    formatting.FormattingApplied = true;
                }
                catch(FormatException)
                {
                    formatting.FormattingApplied = false;
                }
            }

        }
```

Now it works well in my application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to convert bytes to Megabytes.

```
public double ConvertBytesToMegabytes(long bytes)
{
    return (bytes / 1024f) / 1024f;
}
```

Then use that on your code on this part.

```
webApplicationName =  ConvertBytesToMegabytes(dt.Rows[0]["AppName"].ToString());
```