# Store a File Size in a database table using file upload controle

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database, visual-studio-2012

I need to save a file size in database table while uploading a file in using upload control.
i am simple pitching my upload control code here.
Please take a look.

```
protected void UploadFileControl(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
    string contentType = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType;
    using (Stream fs = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream)
    {
        using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
        {
            byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(con))
            {
                string str = "INSERT INTO XYZ VALUES (@FileName, @ContentType, @Data)";
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str))
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileName", fileName);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContentType", contentType);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data", bytes);
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is simple upload control code.

Comment: `int length = bytes.Length;`

Comment: To make it readable, in KB, MB, GB, https://stackoverflow.com/a/4975942/495455