# Is there a better way to return the next item in a list and loop from the end to the front?

Tags: c#, linq, list, enumeration

I have the following list of **distinct** strings:

"A"
"B"
"C"

If I want the item after A, I get B. After B, I get C. After C, I get A. Currently I have the following code, but for some reason it feels to me that there is a better way to go about this (maybe?).

```
private string GetNext(IList<string> items, string curr)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrWhitespace(curr))
        return items[0];

    var index = items.IndexOf(curr);
    if (index == -1)
        return items[0];

    return (index + 1 == items.Count) ? items[0] : items[index + 1];
}
```

I'm definitely open to a LINQ-esque way of doing this as well :)

Comment: I think that this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/716256/creating-a-circually-linked-list-in-c  is what you're looking for

Comment: @hyp: Well, this would work if the parameter being passed in was a `CircularLinkedList<T>`, but it is just an `IList<T>`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think maybe you can change the line

```
return (index + 1 == items.Count) ? items[0] : items[index + 1];
```

for something like

```
return items[(index + 1) % items.Count];
```

Comment: Good improvement, I'll take that. Though it should be (index + 1) right?

Comment: I don't think so, because in your array Count = 3 and when you get Index = 3 it will return 3%3 == 0. When you get index = 2 (to return 'C') you will get it right 2%3 = 2

Comment: Except index is zero-based, so I would never get 3 back for the third item, instead i'd get 2. The first item would return 0. Also, as a bonus I can remove the `if (index == -1)` check because `(-1 + 1) % Anything` is zero always. Yay.

Comment: just to mention: this is neither safe against empty lists not against a null reference, but the original implementation isn't, either.

Comment: @eFloh: Yea, I didn't get to the part where I check against a null or empty list, which should throw exceptions. I just haven't added my exception handling (Contracts) yet.

Answer (score 7):

The solution you have is functionally correct but it's performance leaves a little to be desired.  Typically when dealing with a list style structure you would expect that `GetNext` would return a result in O(1) time yet this solution is O(N).

```
public sealed class WrappingIterator<T> {
  private IList<T> _list;
  private int _index;
  public WrappingIterator<T>(IList<T> list, int index) {
    _list = list;
    _index = index;
  }
  public T GetNext() {
    _index++;
    if (_index == _list.Count) {
      _index = 0;
    }
    return _list[_index];
  }

  public static WrappingIterator<T> CreateAt(IList<T> list, T value) {
    var index = list.IndexOf(value);
    return new WrappingIterator(list, index);
  }
}
```

The initial call to `CreateAt` is O(N) here but subsequent calls to `GetNext` are O(1).

```
IList<string> list = ...;
var iterator = WrappingIterator<string>.CreateAt(list, "B");
Console.WriteLine(iterator.GetNext());  // Prints C
Console.WriteLine(iterator.GetNext());  // Prints A
Console.WriteLine(iterator.GetNext());  // Prints B
```

Comment: This is a very interesting way of going about it. A bit more complicated than I'd like, but definitely interesting.

Comment: Also, just an FYI. The only reason I did not accept this answer is because the function takes in an `IList<T>`, and I didn't want to create an new iterator for each call to the function.

Answer (score 1):

I can see some optimization if you track the current index rather than the current string, but to do that the list of items would have to be fixed, i.e. not change.

You could also `return items[(index + 1) % items.Count];`

Otherwise that code looks fine to me, but perhaps someone has a more clever solution.

Answer (score 1):

LINQ is not the appropriate tool here.

It sounds as if  a [`LinkedList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7.aspx) would be the better collection here:

```
var linkedItems = new LinkedList<String>(items);
LinkedListNode current = linkedItems.Find("C");
String afterC = current.Next == null ? linkedItems.First.Value : current.Next.Value;
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/169992/284240) are the pros and cons of a LinkedList compared to a List.

Answer (score 1):

A linq way:

```
var result = (from str in list
              let index = list.IndexOf(curr) + 1
              select list.ElementAtOrDefault(index) ?? list[0]).First();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mod operator to simplify this a bit and combine everything into one statement:

```
return items[((String.IsNullOrWhitespace(curr) 
                ? 0 
                : items.IndexOf(curr)) + 1) % items.Count]
```

Its definitely shorter, but i'm not sure weather its more readable, too :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is in the below link, I tried it out and works like charm.

http://www.dotnetperls.com/sort-list