# Looking for circular list solution

Tags: c#, .net, list, collections

I wasn't really sure how to address this question, so I will start with "pseudo" code:

```
List<Player> players = new List<Player>();
players.Add(p1);
players.Add(p2);
players.Add(p3);

while(true) //infinite loop
{
    Player nextOne = players.Get(); // It will always get next player
}
```

I'm looking is a collection/list/buffer/array etc. that will have some kind of *"Get"* method, which return next item, always. And when it reach the end, it will return first item.

Great example would be a card game, like poker: I have list of players.. I always return next player, like in the circle.

My question is: is there already, somewhere in C#/.NET, such collection implemented?
If not, is writing an extension method for `List` the best solution?

Comment: It should be easy enough to build your own....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a circularly linked list in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/716256/creating-a-circularly-linked-list-in-c)

Comment: Don't bother with List, you just need to create an Ienumerable so that MoveNext wraps around.

Comment: @JamesThorpe I'm not sure it is. That one is about Linked list and what's more important doesn't have Servy's answer - which is just perfect. I was looking for infinite loop. I guess I should edit the title, cause it's not accurate. I'll do it soon

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can us the following method to create a sequence that is the infinite repetition of another (presumably finite) sequence.

```
//TODO consider coming up with a better name
public static IEnumerable<T> IterateInfinitely<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> sequence)
{
    while(true)
        foreach(var item in sequence)
            yield return item;
}
```

Using this you can now write:

```
foreach(var player in players.IterateInfinitely())
{
    //TODO do stuff 
}
```

Comment: @singsuyash Yes, it'll iterate infinitely.  That's why the method is named `IterateInfinitely`.

Comment: @Servy I like a programmer who names their methods meaningfully.

Comment: That's great answer, thanks! Although, can you explain how it works exactly (those 3 lines from while till yield)? I guess I need to read more about `yield` :/

Comment: `yield` at its best! Great solution to the problem

Comment: @singsuyash ahh, sorry but can you briefly explain what's happening in those three lines? I can't understand it actually

Comment: @WaynePaterson You can fine lots of information on `yield` online, including in-depth explanations, tutorials, books, articles, examples, and so on.  It's well beyond the scope of an SO comment to explain the entire feature.