# Create circular doubly linked list

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, circular-list

I have the next code:

```cs
static LinkedList<Entry> items = new LinkedList<Entry>();
public static Entry runner;
```

`Entry` is a struct that stores information from a database row.

With the next function I add `Entry` items to the list:

```cs
public void Prepare()
{
    // Makes connection to DB
    while(dbReader.Read())
    {
        Entry entry = new Entry(item1, item n);
        items.AddLast(entry);
    }
    runner = items.First.Value;
}
```

Then I call a function that correctly sets the values of that `runner` to the graphic elements on a window.

With two buttons I am able to move forward and backwards on that list while updating all the graphic items correctly, except in the next cases:

1. When trying to go to the previous node while being at the first node.
2. When trying to go to the next node while being at the last one.

How would I solve this? I want to make it behave as a circular doubly linked list.
I know that `System.Collections.Generic`´s `LinkedList` works as a single/normal/classic doubly linked list.

This is the code of the buttons:

```cs
private void previousButton()
{
    runner = items.Find(runner).Previous.Value;
    // Call function to set items<node> to graphical elements
}
```

`nextButton()` works exactly the same but uses `Next` instead of `Previous`.

I already tried to do `runner = items.Find(runner).Previous.Value ?? items.Last.Value;` [as suggested here,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716256/creating-a-circularly-linked-list-in-c) but it says that `?? operator cannot be asigned to types 'Entry' & 'Entry'`.

On `Prepare()` changing `runner = items.First.Value;` to just `runner = items.First();` makes no difference.

Comment: Sounds like you need to define your own class that works the way you want and use it instead of `LinkedList<T>`. It's not for us to teach you how to do that or do it for you. Put some thought into the problem, do what you can and come back and ask a question if and when you encounter a specific problem. Keep in mind that you can look at the .NET source code if you want to, so you can see how the `LinkedList<T>` class works and make appropriate changes in your own class. You may even be able to inherit `LinkedList<T>`, although I wouldn't count on it.

Comment: @user18387401 I know how to make my own class that behaves as expected, I just want to know how to do it while using Microsoft's libraries.

Comment: `runner = items.Find(runner).Previous?.Value ?? items.Last.Value;`

Comment: @Charlieface that did the trick, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you don't use the exact code provided in the answer at [Creating a circularly linked list in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716256/creating-a-circularly-linked-list-in-c)

Be that as it may, you can fix your immediate problem by adding a `?` null-conditional operator. This is because `Previous` might be `null`, and that would be the basis of coalescing to `null` using `??`.

```cs
runner = items.Find(runner).Previous?.Value ?? items.Last.Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Make Entry into a class instead of a struct and you will be able to use the null coalesce operator on it as you expect. Since you are storing references to Entry instances in a LinkedList, you'll likely get better performance from a class than a struct anyways (unless you have a strong need for struct semantics).