# How to retrieve current application root URL in .net core within a static method?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, uri, asp.net-core-2.0

I am currently using the Request.Scheme and Request.Host to composite Uri object to get AbsoluteUri for my .net core MVC application.

```
Uri location = new Uri($"{Request.Scheme}://{Request.Host}");
string applicationRootURL = location.AbsoluteUri;
```

But this only works in a non-static method.

As I need to re-use this method in another controller, I am thinking to make this action method static. If I do that, the compiler will complaint about the Request.Scheme and Request.Host.

I am wondering what's other options I have to achieve this?

Thank you.

**UPDATE:**

This is what I have for ControllerA with ActionMethodA

```
public class ControllerA
{
    public bool ActionMethodA()
    {
        Uri location = new Uri($"{Request.Scheme}://{Request.Host}");
        string applicationRootURL = location.AbsoluteUri;

        return false;
    }
}
```

And in another ControllerB, I want to ActionMethodB to invoke ActionMethodA from ControllerA:

```
public class ControllerB
{
    public void ActionMethodB()
    {
        var result = ActionMethodA();
    }
}
```

Is creating an Extension Method to the ControllerA is the most proper way to handle this kind of scenario?

Thank you.

Comment: Make in an extension method of HttpContext...

Comment: Sorry, didn't figure out how. But plan to implement the solution without making the method static.

Comment: It's one of the most basic and most commonly used features in C# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods

Answer (score 1):

You can also define an extension method directly for the [HttpRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httprequest?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DDE-DE%26k%3Dk(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpRequest);k(SolutionItemsProject);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=aspnetcore-2.0) class and use the [BuildAbsolute](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.extensions.urihelper.buildabsolute?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DDE-DE%26k%3Dk(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions.UriHelper.BuildAbsolute);k(SolutionItemsProject);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=aspnetcore-2.0) method of the [UriHelper](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.extensions.urihelper?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DDE-DE%26k%3Dk(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions.UriHelper);k(SolutionItemsProject);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=aspnetcore-2.0) class to build the uri.

```
public static class HttpRequestExtensions
{
    public static string GetURI(this HttpRequest request)
    {
        return UriHelper.BuildAbsolute(request.Scheme, request.Host);
    }
}
```

And use it:

```
public IActionResult ContollerMethod()
{
    var uri = Request.GetURI();

    // your code
}
```

Comment: Thanks. What I want is making the ControllerMethod to be static, so in another Controller, I can invoke this ControllerMethod like var result = ControllerMethod(); directly. Is it possible?

Comment: @XiaoHan There is not an instance reference to a request object in a static method. So I do not think it is possible.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any other way I can get application URL within a static method?

Comment: @XiaoHan Within a parameterless static method? I do not think there is any other way to accomplish it.

Comment: Not necessarily, can pass any parameter.

Comment: @XiaoHan So basically it is certainly possible to define a static method like this one ```public static bool ActionMethodA(HttpRequest request)``` and call it from an another controller with an appropriate request parameter. But even though it works, it is not a right solution, because one controller should not be responsible for a request of another one.

Comment: I can isolate this static method into a helper/util class to be able to shared and invoked by multiple controller. But not sure if the URL information can be retrieved within this static method.

Comment: @XiaoHan Yes, it is also an option. You can get the URL information the same way using ```HttpRequest``` object as a parameter of the static method. Further helpful reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646328/extension-methods-vs-static-utility-class

Answer (score -1):

You can write an extension method to a controller or HttpContext object. In the following example I have added an extension method to the controller.

```
 public static class ControllerExtensions
{
    public static string GetURI(this Controller controller)
    {
        Uri location = new Uri($"{ controller.Request.Scheme}://{controller.Request.Host}");
        string applicationRootURL = location.AbsoluteUri;
        return applicationRootURL;
    }
}
```

Once the extension method is written you can call it in the following manner.

```
public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var url = this.GetURI();
        return View();
    }
```

**Make sure to import namespace of an extension method in your calling code**

Comment: If I want to make Index() static, is it still working?