# What is so great about extension methods?

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods, static-methods

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What Advantages of Extension Methods have you found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487904/what-advantages-of-extension-methods-have-you-found)

All right, first of all, I realize this sounds controversial, but I don't mean to be confrontational. I am asking a serious question out of genuine curiosity (or maybe *puzzlement* is a better word).

Why were extension methods ever introduced to .NET? What benefit do they provide, aside from making things look nice (and by "nice" I mean "deceptively like instance methods")?

To me, any code that uses an extension method like this:

```
Thing initial = GetThing();
Thing manipulated = initial.SomeExtensionMethod();
```

is misleading, because it implies that `SomeExtensionMethod` is an instance member of `Thing`, which misleads developers into believing (at least as a gut feeling... you may deny it but I've definitely observed this) that (1) `SomeExtensionMethod` is probably implemented efficiently, and (2) since `SomeExtensionMethod` actually looks like it's *part* of the `Thing` class, surely it will remain valid if `Thing` is revised at some point in the future (as long as the author of `Thing` knows what he/she's doing).

But the fact is that extension methods don't have access to protected members or any of the internal workings of the class they're extending, so they're just as prone to breakage as any other static methods.

We all know that the above could easily be:

```
Thing initial = GetThing();
Thing manipulated = SomeNonExtensionMethod(initial);
```

To *me*, this seems a lot more, for lack of a better word, **honest**.

What am I missing? Why do extension methods exist?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487904/what-advantages-of-extension-methods-have-you-found

Comment: @Zarembisty: Thanks, I had honestly searched for a duplicate before posting this but hadn't found that one somehow. If people want to close this, that's understandable.

Comment: I found SO search to be just so-so; Google always finds the answers though (and thankfully more and more of the answers point back to SO)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Extension methods were needed to make Linq work in the clean way that it does, with method chaining. If you have to use the "long" form, it causes the function calls and the parameters to become separated from each other, making the code very hard to read. Compare:

```
IEnumerable<int> r = list.Where(x => x > 10).Take(5)
```

versus

```
// What does the 5 do here?
IEnumerable<int> r = Enumerable.Take(Enumerable.Where(list, x => x > 10), 5);
```

Like anything, they can be abused, but extension methods are really useful when used properly.

Comment: I know this question is closed, but this was my favorite answer.

Comment: Along with chaining, one more thing I want to add its help us to extending the behavior of the class without actual changing in the class. Hence it help us to use "Open Closed Principle"- A class should be open for extension but closed for Modification.

Answer (score 6):

I think that the main upside is *discoverability*. Type `initial` and a dot, and there you have all the stuff that you can do with it. It's a lot harder to find static methods tucked away in some class somewhere else.

Comment: Isn't this really more a consequence of Visual Studio's functionality, though, rather than an inherent benefit of extension methods as part of C#/.NET?

Comment: @Dan: yes, if you use another editor that does not discover the extension methods and show them as Intellisense does, that benefit is gone.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, in the `Thing manipulated = SomeNonExtensionMethod(initial);` case, SomeNonExtensionMethod is based on exactly the same assumptions like in the `Thing manipulated = initial.SomeExtensionMethod();` case. Thing can change, SomeExtensionMethod can break. That's life for us programmers.

Second, when I see `Thing manipulated = initial.SomeExtensionMethod();`, it doesn't tell me exactly where SomeExtensionMethod() is implemented. Thing could inherit it from TheThing, which inherits it from TheOriginalThing. So the "misleading" argument leads to nowhere. I bet the IDE takes care of leading you to the right source, doesn't it?

What's so great? It makes code more consistent. If it works on a string, it looks like if it was a member of string. It's ugly to have several `MyThing.doThis()` methods and several `static ThingUtil.doSomethingElse(Mything thing)` methods in another class.

Comment: To your first point: my point is that the two are in fact the same, but the `SomeNonExtensionMethod` version is less misleading because it doesn't trick you into thinking the method is actually part of the class definition.

Comment: To your second point: at least if you call an instance member, you know it is implemented internally by the class, which means at the very least it has access to protected members and *should* be guaranteed to continue to work whenever the class is updated.

Comment: To your last point: to say it's "ugly" to have static methods do work on an object strikes me as very subjective. I'm having trouble seeing the benefit. I might wish the C# design team would allow replacing curly braces with square brackets because that looks prettier to me; that doesn't mean for them to do that would improve the language.

Comment: Dan: First: I don't think it matters a lot whether or not it is part of the class definition or not. Either it works as expected, or it doesn't.

Comment: Dan: Second: As an outsider, I don't know anything about protected members. I don't care how SomeExtensionMethod() does what it does. Too much knowledge about that leads to assumptions, possibily to hidden dependencies. WOrk whenever the class is updated: I guess you use extension methods for classes that are very stable, like string. You wouldn't use that for your own classes, since you can always change _them_ instead.

Comment: Dan: Third: ThingUtil.staticDoSomething(Thing it) is ugly because this is the functional decomposition antipattern. Technically, the extension methods are not better, but at least it's less visible.

Answer (score 0):

SO you can extend someone else's class. not yours... that's the advantage.
(and you can say.. oh I wish they implement this / that.... you just do it yourself..)

Comment: Hell - @Zarembisty is so right - go to that like he posted. you get everyting there ! stackoverflow.com/questions/487904/… – Zarembisty.

Comment: My point is that they don't give you any more power than simply using static methods does.

Answer (score 0):

they are great for automatically mixing in functionality based on Interfaces that a class inherits without that class having to explicitly re implement it.

Linq makes use of this a lot.

Great way to decorate classes with extra functionality.   Most effective when applied to an Interface rather than a specific class.  Still a good way to extend Framework classes though.

Answer (score 0):

It's just convenient syntactic sugar so that you can call a method with the same syntax regardless of whether it's actually part of the class.  If party A releases a lib, and party B releases stuff that uses that lib, it's easier to just call everything with class.method(args) than to have to remember what gets called with method(class, args) vs. class.method(args).