# C# wrapper for objects

Tags: c#, wrapper

I'm looking for a way to create a generic wrapper for any object.
The wrapper object will behave just like the class it wraps, but will be able to have more properties, variable, methods etc., for e.g. object counting, caching etc.

Say the wrapper class be called *Wrapper*, and the class to be wrapped be called *Square* and has the constructor *Square(double edge_len)* and the properties/methods *EdgeLength* and *Area*, I would like to use it as follows:

```
Wrapper<Square> mySquare = new Wrapper<Square>(2.5);  /* or */ new Square(2.5);
Console.Write("Edge {0} -> Area {1}", mySquare.EdgeLength, mySquare.Area);
```

Obviously I can create such a wrapper class for each class I want to wrap, but I'm looking for a general solution, i.e. `Wrapper<T>` which can handle both primitive and compound types (although in my current situation I would be happy with just wrapping my own classes).

Suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: You can't do this with C# up to 3.0. Version 4.0, however, might let you do this via the new dynamic type system.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DynamicProxy](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/) from the Castle project might be the solution for you.

Comment: +1, yes - the question is clearly looking for a proxy implementation. DynamicProxy is widely used in the .NET open source world (NMock2, NHibernate, Ninject, etc. all use it). The only important caveat is that you won't be able to use a proxy for sealed classes.

Comment: Thanks! This really looks like the solution I was looking for (although I'll have to dig more into it).

Answer (score 4):

Use [Decorator pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707401/please-help-me-understand-the-decorator-pattern-with-real-world-example/2707425#2707425) or write [extension methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487904/what-advantages-of-extension-methods-have-you-found).

Comment: Thanks. Decorator patterns are not suitable, I think, since they require me to change my entire program to use them, and I would like the wrapper to be transparent to the user of T. Regarding extension methods - can you use a similar method to add a variable to the class (i.e. to each object)? Or only methods?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this:

```
public class Wrapper<T>
{
    public readonly T Object;

    public Wrapper(T t)
    {
        Object = t;
    }
}
```

And then you could use it as follows:

```
Wrapper<Square> mySquare = new Wrapper<Square>(new Square(2.5));
Console.Write("Edge {0} -> Area {1}", mySquare.Object.EdgeLength, mySquare.Object.Area);
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's what I'm trying to avoid. I would like the wrapper to be transparent to the user of T.

Comment: This Answer help me a lot :D