# How can I format numbers in C# so 12523 becomes "12K", 2323542 becomes "2M", etc?

Tags: c#, number-formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Format Number like StackoverFlow (rounded to thousands with K suffix)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134161/format-number-like-stackoverflow-rounded-to-thousands-with-k-suffix)

How can I format numbers in C# so 12523.57 becomes "12K", 2323542.32 becomes "2M", etc?

I don't know how to append the correct number abbreviation (K, M, etc) and show the appropriate digits?

So,

```
1000 = 1K  
2123.32 = 2K  
30040 = 30k  
2000000 = 2M
```

Is there a built in way in C# to do this?

Comment: this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134161/format-number-like-stackoverflow-rounded-to-thousands-with-k-suffix

Comment: No, it isn't.  That deals with specifically formating for only one suffix, "K".

Comment: Maybe this is closer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128618/c-file-size-format-provider . @Teradact - you only need minor tweaks to make it work, the code is basically the same.

Comment: look through the comments on the answer—there is a one-liner that enables the use of `M` as well.

Answer (score 9):

I don't think this is standard functionality in C#/.Net, but it's not that difficult to do this yourself.  In pseudocode it would be something like this:

```
if (number>1000000)
   string = floor(number/1000000).ToString() + "M";
else if (number > 1000)
   string = floor(number/1000).ToString() + "K";
else
   string = number.ToString();
```

If you don't want to truncate, but round, use round instead of floor.

Answer (score 0):

There's no built in way, you'll have to roll your own routine, similar to this:

```
public string ConvertNumber(int num)
{
    if (num>= 1000)
        return string.Concat(num/ 1000, "k");
    else
        return num.ToString();
}
```